# How to Loop through Socket.onmessage() - javascript

Tags: javascript, sockets, for-loop, socket.io

I dont understand why my simple forloop not printing the console.log.

i just started learning and implementing Socket concept in javascript.

Could some one tell me, is that any special things to know and handle socket concept.?

am sharing my very minimal example snippets.

sample data structure as follows

```
let obj = [{ "posts": [ { "id": 1, "title": "Post 1" }, { "id": 2, "title": "Post 2" }, { "id": 3, "title": "Post 3" } ], "comments": [ { "id": 1, "body": "some comment", "postId": 1 }, { "id": 2, "body": "some comment", "postId": 1 } ], "profile": { "name": "typicode" } }]

socket.on('message', function(data) { 
for (let i = 0; i < data.length;i++ ){
    console.log(data[i]);
    }    
  });
```

Thanks you

Comment: Are you sure that `data` is an array?

Comment: yes am sure, i'm trying to get json data

Comment: `length` is used in case of array but JSON is object. Could you show us your data pattern?

Comment: @MH2K9 could you check my updated question. i have include my sample data

Comment: data is OK. Please check weather the socket connection was established and respond or not.  `message` function is invoked when socket server response successfuly.

Comment: @worstCoder you mention that not printing the console.log in the loop. But if you put the console.log before the loop, like this :

     socket.on('message', function(data) { console.log(data);
   
  });

What information does log show ? It prints "undefined" or like this [{...}] ?

Comment: @Kuo-hsuanHsu there is no error and no data

Comment: Then, I suggest that the socket message is not invoked, like MH2k9 says. Maybe you should check the socket connection? 
`socket.on('Connect', function(conn) {
        console.log("connect success!");
     
        conn.on('disconnect', function() { 
            console.log("oops! disconnect!"); 
        });
        conn.on('Error', function() { 
            console.log("error happens!"); 
        }); 
   
        conn.on('message', function(data) { 
           console.log('message received success'); 
           console.log(data); 
        });
    }); `

Then see what happen ?